# Как лучше разметить?

Tags: html, инспекция-кода, разметка, бэм

```
<div class="catalog">
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <h2 class="header catalog__header">Lorem</h2>
    <a href="" class="btn catalog__btn">Lorem</a>
    <div class="catalog__item">
      <img class="catalog__img" src="img/image-product.jpg" alt="" width="306" height="206">
      <div class="catalog__inner">
        <h3 class="catalog__title">Title name</h3>
        <b class="catalog__price">300</b>
        <a href="" class="btn catalog__btn_price">Description</a>
        <a href="" class="btn catalog__btn_price">Buy</a>
      </div>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как лучше разметить данную структуру по бэм? Все оставить как есть или лучше разбить по блокам вложенные элементы

Например так

```
<div class="catalog">
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <h2 class="header catalog__header">Lorem ipsum.</h2>
    <a href="" class="btn catalog__btn">Lorem.</a>
    <div class="catalog__item">
      <img class="catalog__img" src="img/image-product.jpg" alt="" width="306" height="206">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <h3 class="item-inner__title">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
        <b class="item-inner__price">300</b>
        <a href="" class="btn btn_price">Lorem.</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn_price">Lorem.</a>
      </div>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: БЭМ это то ноу-хау от Яндекса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй вариант правильный. Каталог — это блок, товар — это тоже блок, а не элемент.

В первом случае у вас формируется зависимость товара от каталога, потому вы не сможете его использовать где-нибудь в другом месте, хотя это может понадобиться.

Comment: А если item-inner представляет собой часть catalog-item?

Comment: Тогда я бы сделал примесь: `div class="catalog__item item-inner">` для конкретного этого случая, но товар в любом случае стоит выделить отдельным блоком.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/44rmzh14/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/44rmzh14/2/ лучше так.

Comment: и потом все эти блоки нужно будет по отдельным папкам раскидывать?

Comment: Это уже зависит от того, как вы внедрили БЭМ, какая архитектура у проекта и т.п., в общем виде тут нет однозначного решения. Я обычно каждый блок выделяю в отдельный файл и кладу в папку `blocks`.

Comment: А для небольших проектов, например для одной страницы или нескольких страниц раскидывать блоки по папкам не имеет смысла?

Comment: Если вы точно уверены, что это останется одной страницей и нет какого-нибудь готового архитектурного шаблона, то, думаю, этим заниматься особенно нет смысла. Но если это лендинг, который грозится стать интернет-магазином, то я бы сразу потратил чутка времени на структуру.